# Java method calling and execution procedure

Tags: java

have created two method in an single class file, like `methodA` and `methodB`
inside the methodA i called the methodB

```
public void methodA() {
Line 1:---
Line 2:---
Line 3:methodB();
Line 4:---
}    

public String methodB() {
Line 1:---
Line 2:---
Line 3:return String;
}
```

after executing the `methodB` i want to continue the execution in `methodA` from the `Line 4`, please suggested with an idea

Comment: I don't understand what exactly is the problem? When `methodB` returns it will start execution from next line.

Comment: This is how it's supposed to work. Atleast try it..

Comment: The behavior you have mentioned ... that is how java works

Comment: If you are confused about the `return` statement, it only exits the function that calls it, in this case it exits `methodB` and resumes process in `methodA`

Answer (score 0):

That's how it will work.

Unless you call `System.exit()` or somehow exit the program in `methodB`, then `methodA` will continue to execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String methodA() {
    Line 1:---
    Line 2:---
    Line 3:----
    Line 4:---
    return "";
}    

public String methodB() {
    Line 1:---
    Line 2:---
    Line 3:return methodA();
}
```

Comment: How does this even work? You call `methodB()` inside `methodA()`, and call `methodA()` inside `methodB()`? Hmmm

Comment: sorry i forget to remove methodB in method A

Comment: I think you have it backwards now

Comment: may i know drew pierce am i correct or wrong let me know